# ffmpeg is ignoring start_number flag

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to cut a video into smaller parts using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 00:20:00 -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 -start_number 3 "output%03d.mp4"
```

It works, but it creates file with following names: (starting at zero)
output000.mp4 output001.mp4 and so on.

but I want file names like:
output003.mp4 output004.mp4 and so on.

Its ignoring "-start_number 3" option as given here:
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html

How can I do this in a "single command" format as given above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option is `-segment_start_number`.

See [FFmpeg segment muxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) for more info.

Comment: Works perfectly! Many many thanks for this!